# How to set Excel option button value (via python)?

Tags: python, excel, button

---

Hey there,

I'm writing a python plugin for a geo referencing program called QGIS where I want an Excel sheet to do all my calculations for me. For different data points I need to set certain input values into the spreadsheet (which was already written by someone else).
I'm fine setting the simple int values (using win32com.client) with 
sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = value
Setting an option button value, I'd expect (and thinnk I read somewhere) to go like so: sheet.opt_name.Value = True
but the console keeps returning (though opt_name exists and is used in VB)
"AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'opt_name'"

Any ideas what's could be wrong with that? Am I on the right track? Is is even possible to do via python or do I need to dive into VB?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the option button as a shape on the sheet

I don't know how you access the excel object model in python, but in vb it's something like

```
YourSheetObject.Shapes("opt_name").Value = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but I found a working solution on a German site (http://www.spotlight-wissen.de/archiv/message/1112740.html). Seems Like you need to used different accessing methods depending on how you button was created. Thanks for your help.